# How to get function Argument from Stack - Assembly

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-64, calling-convention

I've been trying forever to put a value into a passed by address argument. It's on the stack somewhere.

The function is called through a C++ program linked to the assembly program. It passes in 8 arguments, one of which is a float. First argument is in `RDI` and the 2nd to last is in `r9`. The final argument, the one I'm trying to get is somewhere on the stack.

I've tried every possible offset it seems, and none seem to work. I've managed to change the value of some other variable passed in, yet not the one I want! The professor wrote [rbp + 16] next to it, implying the address can be accessed through that, but it doesn't change the value at all when I try to change the value:

`movss [rbp+16], xmm0`

At the moment, I'm pushing `RBP` at the start of the function, moving 100 into eax, putting eax into xmm0 (cvtsi2ss), and then moving xmm0 into rbp+whateverOffset.

Is there something I'm missing? Any insight is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT:

This is done on Ubuntu. Here's the Assembly Code:

````
global  Error
Error:

push rbp

mov eax, 100
cvtsi2ss xmm0, eax
movss [rbp+16], xmm0```


ret
````

This is called using this C++ Code:

```
Error(array, length, PrValue, &One, &Two, &Three, &Four, &Five);
```

The variable I want to access is "Five", I want to move a value into the memory address that's moved in. All values are floats except for the second which is an integer, array is float array.

```
extern "C" void Error(float[], unsigned int, float,
        float *, float *, float *, float *, float *);
```

Comment: Please post the exact signature of your function and what operating system you are programming for (calling convention varies depending on operating system).  Also, please post the complete code you tried.  Post the code, don't just paraphrase it.  It might also be useful to post the C++ code you used to call your function.

Comment: Just did, sorry if it was too vague

Comment: Look at what a compiler does for a C / C++ version of `Error`.  Compilers will know where to look for your vars.  e.g. look at `g++ -S -fverbose-asm` output.  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38552509)

Comment: @zapshe Still too vague.  I need the actual declaration of `Error`; I don't really care about the code you use to call it, but the declaration is important.

Comment: @fuz Added that just now, slipped my mind.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'll try that out and see what I get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On function entry, the first stack arg is at `[rsp + 8]`.**

Your function does `push rbp` to save the caller's RBP, but you didn't do `mov rbp, rsp` to make RBP a frame pointer.  You also don't `pop rbp` at the end.

**After setting up RBP as a traditional frame pointer, the first stack arg will be at `[rbp + 16]`**.

`movss [rbp+16], xmm0` stores xmm0 somewhere into *your caller's* stack frame, if your caller was compiled with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` (the default at -O0).  i.e. it uses whatever value your caller happened to leave in RBP, not your own frame pointer.

If you wanted to use a pointer arg that was passed on the stack, you need to first load it into an integer register and *then* dereference it.  You don't want to just over-write the arg like `argfive = float`, you want `*argfive = float`.

Comment: Sorry, left out the ```pop rbp``` at the end. Thanks for the information, I just a bit ago found the offset I needed, which was 72 for some reason. I tried many offsets before finding it. It may not be the correct approach and it may be changing the value in a way that it shouldn't, but this assembly class is giving me a "if it works, don't care" mindset. Thanks again!

Comment: @zapshe:  72?  That makes no sense.  Relative to what?  If you're still not using `mov rbp, rsp` after `push rbp`, you're depending on details of the caller that aren't part of the calling convention.  Are you bypassing the pointer and storing directly into `Five` in the caller's stack frame, without using the pointer it passed you?

Comment: I did not as you said mov RSP into RBP. I spent some time looking for the correct offset, and 72 makes me think I probably did simply store it directly into ```Five```. I was looking at the memory addresses of the other variables that came in, and then looked at the memory address RBP was looking at, and found a difference of 68 if I remember right. It was in the sixties at least. And so I tested offsets greater than that and it happened to be 72. I'm sure the correct offset is much smaller had I done it correctly.